# Null byte injection in Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, security

Is there no need to consider the null byte injection vulnerability when writing code in Python?

I know how to write (and it means how to avoid) vulnerable code for null byte injection in some languages:

http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246949/Null%20Byte%20Injection

but I don't know in Python. Does anyone know how to write vulnerable code?

Comment: By calling a vulnerable non-Python routine.

Comment: Python does not read NULL byte values (human). A null value in the C language is a string-break identifier, and there is no term ' string ' in that language. If the Python application you are referring to is accessing a C library/application, the content is often checked. In addition, Python also locks the module and system directories of Web services. Check out the first comment for a short answer.

Comment: @dsgdfg - python doesn't lock module and system directories of web services. Its common to have multiple layers of protection (the web server has a user name and the OS stricts, then the web server also has its own rights assignment). But its not python itself. If I run `SimpleHTTPServer` it gets anything my user account gets.

Comment: Django is python-cgi application(based wsgi), and most cgi application starting with path. İf you run djange server without path definition you got a big problem.

Comment: Python string objects can contain NUL and I think there could be vulnerabilities. The low level `PyBytes_AS_STRING` doesn't check but the `PyBytes_AsStringAndSize` does. The file system API seems to do a good job. But that doesn't mean there isn't a problem lurking in there somewhere. Scrub those URLs!

Comment: Ummmh... I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean. I'm weak in Python. Is there an example code?